"Range Not Satisfiable" when trying to execute or jack-in a clojure application that uses deps.edn
I have a simple clojure app with the following dependencies:
 :deps
 {org.scicloj/clay {:mvn/version "2-beta17"}
  org.scicloj/noj {:mvn/version "2-alpha9.1"}
  aerial.hanami/aerial.hanami {:mvn/version "0.20.0"}}

when trying to launch the app (or the REPL from VScode/Canva) I get an error and the execution/jack-in fails with: 416 "Range Not Satifiable" for the dependency: same/ish "0.1.6"

The problem is not linked to a specific dependency, and seems to be known see this question on clojureverse.
The solution (or at least, one solution that works in all cases) as proposed in the linked clojurians-log entry is to remove the maven caching (for the library/dependency with the problem or - what I did - all of it):
rm -fR .m2

